# Cost breakdown for Online payments. Wix vs SquareSpace vs WordPress

Tags: wordpress, squarespace, velo

Can anyone help me out with how much it costs to have online payments for Wix/SquareSpace/WordPress?

I finally found out that for Wix you need to have at least the Business Basic plan in value of 20 Eur/Month. And then 2.9% + 30 cents for Paypal, and then 1.4% + 100 cents for Credit Card.

How much is for SquareSpace and WordPress? Do you need a plan in there as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SquareSpace but **WordPress is completely free**. Moreover, you can easily manage any business with WordPress. Some examples of WordPress websites, you can check if you want.

https://news.microsoft.com/

https://www.hackerrank.com/

https://about.fb.com/news/

https://github.blog/

https://www.whitehouse.gov/

https://blog.playstation.com/

https://www.angrybirds.com/

https://evernote.com/

https://elementor.com/

I hope it will benefit you